# text-overflow: ellipsis is not working in table

Tags: html, css

I have two HTML elements - one is `div` another is a `table`. both of them have two elements - div has `p` and table has `td`. Both of them have the same style.

**Code:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

p, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100px; background-color: red">
  <p width="50px">
    Hello world
  </p>
  <p width="50px">
    Hello world
  </p>
</div>

<table style="background-color: green">
  <tr width="100px">
    <td width="50px">Hello World</td>
    <td width="50px">Hello World</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And their parent has `100px` width. Actually, I want them to truncate if their size overflowed. For `div`, I get my desired output but in `table`, I do not get the same result. why does this happen? Is it because `table` has a different default style than `div`?

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/alimurrazi/amqkgofu/28/)

Comment: Table cell =/= div. Ellipsis won't even work inside a regular div, to be honest, because it requires a number of other (non-default) properties set to specific values, in order for it to work. Wrap your cell's content with a div[,](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work) then apply style to that div instead of the cell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens because of the display property in table. You need to give a `display: block` to make ellipsis work, but it kind of removes how tables should work.

The better thing would be to wrap your `td` contents inside a `div`
and change your CSS.

Option 2 would be using `max-width to your` td`.

```
<td width="50px">
  <div>Hello World</div>
</td>
```

CSS to:

```
td>div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50px
}
```

OR Just add max-width

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

p,
td>div,td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100px; background-color: red">
  <p width="50px">
    Hello world
  </p>
  <p width="50px">
    Hello world
  </p>
</div>

<table style="background-color: green">
  <tr width="100px">
    <td width="50px">
      <div>

        Hello World</div>
    </td>
    <td width="50px">
      <div>

        Hello World</div>
    </td>
    <td width="50px">
      Hello World
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This hack is no longer required. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323243/625444

Answer (score 2):

To clip text with an ellipsis when it overflows a table cell, you will need to set the max-width CSS property on each td class for the overflow to work.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
td
{
 max-width: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100px; background-color: red">
  <p width="50px">
    Hello world
  </p>
  <p width="50px" >
    Hello world
  </p>
</div>

<table  style="background-color: green">
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World</td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving width to tr and td, give width to the table.

```css
table {
  background-color: green;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100px;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello World</td>
      <td>Hello World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```